# solve system equation: $ a \cdot b = 3 \cdot a-b+1, b \cdot c = 3 \cdot b - c + 1, c \cdot a = 3 \cdot c - a + 1$

Tags: systems-of-equations, symmetric-polynomials

I want to solve this system of equations but i'm stuck.
Here is it:

$$ a \cdot b = 3 \cdot a - b + 1 $$
$$ b \cdot c = 3 \cdot b - c + 1 $$ 
$$ c \cdot a = 3 \cdot c - a + 1 $$

Comment: If the $*$ means multiplication, it is customary to not write the $*$ or $\times$ (\times) sign or $\cdot$ (\cdot) sign. If you really want to show some symbol for multiplication it is always better to use $\cdot$.

Comment: thanks, for correction, I didn't know about \cdot

Comment: Dear @Arbnor Zeqiri, You should also be able to solve on of your old questions ([link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1320486/solve-system-equation-sqrta-sqrtb-sqrtc-1-sqrtb-sqrtc)) using the approach discussed in @ Jürgen Böhm's answer.

Comment: Dear @Arbnor Zequiri, I deleted my answer, because the argument I used is not correct: Just because with solution $(a,b,c)$ also the triple $(b,c,a)$ is a solution one can not conclude that $a=b=c$, in principle $(a,b,c)$ could be all different. A calculation (with Maple) shows that indeed $a=b=c$, but one cannot, I think, omit such a calculation, which can be done by using Gröbner bases or by using the argument of G. Sassatelli.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: If $a\neq-1\wedge b\neq-1\wedge c\neq -1$

$$\begin{cases}b=\frac{3a+1}{1+a}\\c=\frac{3b+1}{1+b}\\a=\frac{3c+1}{1+c}\end{cases}$$

What happens if you substitute (1) in (2) and, after that, (2) in (3)?